# Preventing 304 NOT MODIFIED response in Tomcat

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets, caching, servlet-filters

If a resource (index.html) is already cached in the client, for example using response header:

```
"Cache-Control": "max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
```

How can I prevent tomcat to respond with a `304 Not Modified`in the **next** request to the server? I would like to force the server to respond with 200 instead of 304 no matter what. 
I tried to set

```
httpResp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
httpResp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
httpResp.setHeader("Expires", "0");
```

but it only works in the SECOND request. The first request still gets 304.
I tried to override the `if-modified-since` header using `HttpServletRequestWrapper` with values in the past such as `Mon, 06 Dec 2010 01:34:46 GMT` with no luck - client still gets 304 responses although the file was modified in 2015.
Is there any way I can prevent 304 responses? maybe via tomcat configuration?

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure if this will help but you could try the following -**

1. Delete the browser cache to start from scratch and test whether this works or not
2. Adapted from another ServerFault question -

https://serverfault.com/questions/40205/how-do-i-disable-tomcat-caching-im-having-weird-static-file-problems?answertab=votes#tab-top

*You might have to delete the application cache folder in /work/Catalina/localhost after changing the cachingAllowed flag.
Configuration can be introduced in server.xml as*

```
    <Context className="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext"
             cachingAllowed="false"
             charsetMapperClass="org.apache.catalina.util.CharsetMapper"
             cookies="true" 
             reloadable="false" 
             wrapperClass="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper">
    </Context>
```